# SonicWall firewall setting up RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, firewall, remote-access

I want to setup an RDP connection from the outside into my network I have a SonicWall NSA 220 what is the process involved? How secure is this option? are their other options available to this device that I am not considering which are better in terms of security (VPN)?

A simple guide would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPN would be much better, whether SSL or IPSEC.  However, there should be an available wizard to enable the port forwarding for RDP or any other type of connection.  Essentially, you select the public IP, translated private IP, and original and translated services (ports).  Without the wizard, you have to setup at least one NAT rule and one WAN->LAN FW rule.